# Autoexpand UITextView height to contain the complete text loaded dynamically

Tags: ios, uitextview

I have a simple textView who's data gets populated dynamically. I want to resize the height of the textview once the data is populated so that i dont see a vertical scroll nor the text gets clipped.

Could it be done simply by choosing one of those textView modes or do i need to do it programaticaaly?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can do this by adding these few lines of code to your application's:-

```
CGRect frame = textView.frame; 
frame.size.height = textView.contentSize.height; 
textView.frame = frame;
```

Implement this code in th delegate method of textview

```
- (void)textViewDidChange:(UITextView *)textView 
{
// you might have to compare the frames if it needs changing as user might not have added an extra line
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to do it programmatically. Use the [NSString UIKit Additions](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/NSString_UIKit_Additions/Reference/Reference.html) to calculate the height of your UITextView:

```
sizeWithFont:
sizeWithFont:constrainedToSize:
sizeWithFont:constrainedToSize:lineBreakMode:
sizeWithFont:forWidth:lineBreakMode:
sizeWithFont:minFontSize:actualFontSize:forWidth:lineBreakMode:
```